# Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'mm' for update in FROM clause

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, updates

i google this question several time but failed to fix mentioned issue. please help me.

My query:

```
UPDATE meter As mm SET mm.mdi_reset_date='2', mm.write_mdi_reset_date='1'
            WHERE mm.msn IN (SELECT m.msn
            FROM meter m
                INNER JOIN connection con ON con.feeder_id = m.feeder_id
                INNER JOIN consumers co ON co.consumer_id = con.customer_id 
                INNER JOIN customer cs ON co.parent_id = cs.customer_id 
                INNER JOIN cs_group_details cd ON cd.customer_id=cs.customer_id 
                WHERE co.batch_no = '30'
            AND cd.cs_group_id='4');
```

Comment: create temporary table and use that

Comment: please share any other solution to handle this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create temporary table using query

```
CREATE TABLE meter_temp LIKE meter;
```

Now insert data from `meter` to temporary table `meter_temp`

```
INSERT INTO meter_temp SELECT * FROM meter;
```

Use your update query

```
UPDATE meter As mm SET mm.mdi_reset_date='2', mm.write_mdi_reset_date='1'
            WHERE mm.msn IN (SELECT m.msn
            FROM meter_temp m
                INNER JOIN connection con ON con.feeder_id = m.feeder_id
                INNER JOIN consumers co ON co.consumer_id = con.customer_id 
                INNER JOIN customer cs ON co.parent_id = cs.customer_id 
                INNER JOIN cs_group_details cd ON cd.customer_id=cs.customer_id 
                WHERE co.batch_no = '30'
            AND cd.cs_group_id='4');
```

Let me know if it is working or not.

**Edited ::**

```
$subQuery = "SELECT m.msn FROM meter_temp m INNER JOIN connection con ON con.feeder_id = m.feeder_id INNER JOIN consumers co ON co.consumer_id = con.customer_id INNER JOIN customer cs ON co.parent_id = cs.customer_id INNER JOIN cs_group_details cd ON cd.customer_id=cs.customer_id WHERE co.batch_no = '30' AND cd.cs_group_id='4'";
$result = mysqli($con,$query); // assuming you are using mysqli. change as per your code
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $msnArray[] = $row['msn'];
}
$msn = implode(",",$msnArray); // assuming msn is integer and not string.
// if it is string then you have to wrap it in quotes.
// Now run update query
$update = "UPDATE meter SET mdi_reset_date='2', write_mdi_reset_date='1' WHERE msn IN ({$msn})";
$updateResult = mysqli_query($con,$update);
```

Comment: your effort is highly appreciated but i don't want to create temp. table. because meter table has data in GB's.

Comment: Then I think you should run the subquery first and then using retrieved `msn` run update query. provided that you are okay with running two quries

Comment: For updating using single query or using two queries?

Comment: please explain both